# create pull request from fork with only certain files

Tags: git

My current repo is ahead of the repo I forked from.  I was wondering, is there a way I can create a new branch off of master, pull in the files I changed, and create a PR from this branch?

The issue is I don't want to create a PR for all of my changes in master.  For example, I have changes to:

```
src/
   file1
   file2
   file3
```

from my master to theirs in my fork.  I want to pull in all there changes, and then only send my changes to file2 in a PR.

Comment: so you know which changes are yours? if so you can cherry-pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a PR branch, create it from `upstream/master` (with upstream being the remote name for the original repo, that you have forked)

```
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b mypr upstream/master
```

From then, as commented, you can cherry-pick your commits (or even [ranges of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309))